# Converting Array of bytes and saving as image Python

Tags: python, image-processing, byte

At the moment I have the following code:

```
    with open("/Users/Dennis/Desktop/Compression/heart.png", "rb") as imageFile:

      f = imageFile.read()

      b = bytearray(f)
```

So `b` is an array of bytes

Now I would like to convert this array of bytes back to a png image and save to desktop.

The bytes are in integer format (0-255)

I have seen a few examples online, some use a module named Image which requires PIL/Pillow but I can't seem to install that on my mac using pip. If this is the only way can someone walk me through how it's done.

If there is an easier alternative I would love to know. Thanks a mill!

Answer (score 0):

If it could be of any help after all this time, I have found on `open cv` web site that you can do a `imwrite`

you may found it [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html).